# Static block covering main column and left sidebar (on 3 columns layout)

Tags: css, magento, layout

I'm trying to figure out how to some content covering the space of main column and left sidebar on 3 columns layout. 
Page have 3 columns in the first part and 2 columns with left sidebar in the lower part.

This is my homepage, I don't need to have a new layout since the main page is the only one using the current 3 columns layout.

What is the best way to get this design?
 Is it possible to make it as a static block?

Comment: Honestly, even if it's just the home page, you will probably want to add a new page layout.

Answer (score 0):

so as first steps i have added this to /app/etc/local.xml

```
 <cms> 
 <layouts> 
 <homepage> 
 <label>Home Page</label> 
 <template>page/home-page.phtml</template> 
 <layout_handle>home_page</layout_handle> 
 </homepage> 
 </layouts> 
 </cms>
```

and created a duplicate of 3 column layout named home-page.phtml :

app\design\frontend......\template\page\home-page.phtml

now i have a new layout but unfortunately i don't know how to edit to get the result.

I feel a bit uncomfortable asking this, but i'm really new to layout design and i have no idea on how to edit my new home-page.phtml, hope you can understand me.

file looks like this:

```
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?> 
    <div class="centerbg">
    <div class="bottombg">
    <div class="topcurve">
    <div class="page">      
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="main-container col3-layout">
            <div class="main">                
                    <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
                    <div class="col-main">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>                 
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>                
            </div>
        </div>      
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>  
    </div></div></div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

i guess i'll need new CSS classes too, right?